# How can I force paragraph to render within a div and expand the divs height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm using [AngularUI-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for tooltips with some custom css. I have a max width on the .tooltip-inner class of 300px.  The .tooltip class is its container and it is absolute positioned. The HTML/CSS looks like this, obfuscated a bit apologies...

```
<div class="tooltip-inner ng-binding" bind-html-unsafe="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum made using yada yada yada. Here are a few helpful definitions for ones requiring a little more explanation.</p>
  <ul>
       <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.</li>
       <li>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyitution.</li>
       <li>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-value="close">Close</a>
</div>

.tooltip-inner {
     padding: 7px;
     min-width: 130px;
     color: #666;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #b8b8b8;
    border-top-color: #a9d0e5;
    border-bottom-color: #b8b8b8;
    background-color: #f3fafd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: .4em .4em 1.2em -0.3em rgba(89,89,89,0.27);
    -moz-box-shadow: .4em .4em 1.2em -0.3em rgba(89,89,89,0.27);
    box-shadow: .4em .4em 1.2em -0.3em rgba(89,89,89,0.27);
    text-shadow: .0555em .0555em .01em rgba(178,178,178,0.7);
}
```

No styles are setting the height, or the position. The child elements have no specific styles that would be causing this behavior as far as I know.

[image: Div height not expanding]

How can I make the div .tooltip-inner expand its height and maintain it's width, well it currently maintains the width, but obvious this is not what I'm shooting for. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the outer div, `tooltip-inner`, style to `overflow:auto`

Comment: I tried that but but it just puts in a horizontal scroll bar and doesn't break the text at all. Basically looks the same except the text is now scrollable. Thank you though for the answer.

Comment: I apologize this should not be down voted. I just meant that I tried it and it did not work for me. I tried to remove the down vote and stackoverflow won't left me. Please let me know how I can correct this. Apologies.